How is Nethermind's Clear formal verification tool different from Certora and Runtime Verification's KEVM?
Nethermind has released a new formal verification tool called Clear.
How is it different from more established tools like Certora and Runtime Verification's KEVM?

The primary difference between Nethermind and the others is that Nethermind focuses on 'interactive theorem proving', which is an approach where a human constructs both the specification (desired behavior of software) and the proof (of the code conforming to said specification). This makes it possible to prove just about anything you can prove with pen and paper.
Certora focuses on 'automated theorem proving', where you write only the specification - the proof is then left for machines to find. This takes much less time, as you don't need a meatsack to write the ruddy proof, but machines are nowhere near as good at writing proofs as humans are, so the kinds of behaviors/properties you can prove that software conforms to is limited to what the machine can prove.
Runtime Verifications is a bit of a mixed bag. They try both automated and interactive approaches, but they're skewed towards automated with things like the K framework or Kontrol.
Nethermind's Clear can be understood as a Lean framework (Lean library, Lean 'thingie') specifically tailored to reason about Yul programs.
